# Memory management and data structures with OpenMPI

Tags: c++, openmp, openmpi

I need help understanding how I can better manage memory in my code. `sizeof(x)=8` (file main.cpp) and this is always equal to the number of processes spawned. How do I ensure that `sizeof(x) = 1` and that it is a 1D array of size num (from main.cpp).

I would like to import utils.h as a static library import. How best should I structure my code? I would also be very grateful if I am pointed to suitable references to be better aware of using ND arrays, vectors and data structures with OpenMPI.

My main.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utils.h>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    float start = 0., end = 1.;
    int num = 100;

    double *x = linspace(start, end, num);


    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        cout << *(x + i) <<endl;
    }


    MPI_Finalize();


    return 0;

}
```

My utils.h is:

```
#ifndef utils_h
#define utils_h


#endif /* utils_h */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;


double * linspace(double start_in, double end_in, unsigned long int num_in)
{
    /* This function generates equally spaced elements and returns
    an array with the results */


    int size, rank;

    double start = static_cast<double>(start_in);
    double end = static_cast<double>(end_in);
    unsigned long int num = static_cast<unsigned long int>(num_in);

    double * linspaced;
    linspaced = new double[num];

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    assert(num!=0);

    if (num == 1)
    {
        *(linspaced) = start_in;
        return linspaced;
    }


    double delta = (end - start) / (num - 1);


    for(int i=rank; i < num - 1; i += size)
    {

        // cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        *( linspaced + i) = start + delta * i;
    }
    linspaced[num-1] = end; // I want to ensure that start and end
    // are exactly the same as the input


    cout << "size-of-linspaced : " << sizeof(linspaced) << endl;
    return linspaced;

}
```

Comment: 1) You have a memory leak here since you allocate and then throw away the pointer to the beginning of the array, so there is no way to call the `delete` on that later.  2) I don't understand your question. You are dividing an array among different ranks and then you want each to get only 1 element of the array?!

Comment: @Arash, I'm new to OpenMPI. I want each rank to get `num/size` elements of the array. `num % size` will be handled by the first rank.

Comment: My first point was not correct. You are not throwing away a pointer. I structured it as the code below. Take a look.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged with OpenMP? It has nothing to do with OpenMP...

Comment: The question is very confusing and makes little sense to me: what's your point with `sizeof`? `sizeof(double*)` is always statically the same for one architecture. What do you mean by "static library import"? Import is not C++ terminology, a header does not make a static library. You might be best off with a good entry level book for C++. At the very least, your question is too broad. It is absolutely out of scope for SO to explain "using ND arrays, vectors and data structures with OpenMPI" in a single answer.